# Having difficulty in implementation of linkedin recommendation api to fetch linkedin recommendation on our website

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Hi as I found on some website by using linkedin api we can fetch your website user's linkedin recommendation to show it on your website as part of user profiles.

So to do this I searched for its implementation & found 2 api code & I tried both but its not working for my side.

First code ,I tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: XXXXXXXXX
  authorize: true
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="authSuccess"></script>
<script>
function authSuccess() {

    var recos_element = jquery("#footer-logo");

    IN.API.Raw("people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,recommendations-received)").method("GET").result(function(result){
            console.log("result",result);
{                   
        for(var key in result.values) {
            var reco = result.values[key];
            recos_element.append($('<p><i><b>' + reco.recommender.firstName + ' ' + reco.recommender.lastName + '</b> says,</i><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + reco.recommendationText + '</p>'));
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Second code I tried:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"> 
        api_key: XXXXXXXXXX
        authorize: true
    </script>  
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function onLinkedInAuth() {
            IN.API.Raw('/people/~:(recommendations-received)')
                .method('GET')
                .result(function(result){

                    var received = result.recommendationsReceived.values;
                    $('<p>')
                        .html('Recommendations: ' + received.length)
                        .appendTo('#recommendations');

                    $.each(received, function(i, data){
                        $('<h3>')
                            .html(data.recommender.firstName + " " + data.recommender.lastName)
                            .appendTo('#recommendations');
                        $('<p>')
                            .html(data.recommendationText)
                            .appendTo('#recommendations');
                    });
            })
        };
    </script>
<script type="in/login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth">
        Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
    </script>
```

I am also using linkedin Member Profile Plugin in this we have to send user's profile-url to fetch his profile in data-id

```
  <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="(Profile URL)" data-format="inline"></script>
```

So should we have to do similar like this for fetching user's recommendtaion.

Please help me for this.

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score -1):

well honestly do not know where you are putting this section of code  and there is very little information about your error inyour code, what I recommend is to use a plugin that will facilitate besides that there implemetation documentation and tutorials, just make a git clone of:

- [Cakephp-Linkedin](https://github.com/inlet/CakePHP-LinkedIn)

and the wiki:

- [tep by step: Setup your controller](https://github.com/inlet/CakePHP-LinkedIn/wiki/1.-Step-by-step:-Setup-your-controller)
- [How to use the API](https://github.com/inlet/CakePHP-LinkedIn/wiki/2.-How-to-use-the-API)